# Querying an array in mongoose along with other keys

Tags: mongoose

I have documents as such:

```
    {
        "_id": "594a78e2fc9d19454bae54fe",
        "name": "Great Name",
        "another_id": 15854,
        "__v": 0,
        "arraything": [
            {
                "name": "cadmium",
                "id": 14,
                "_id": "59520442c65c73249e67fc66"
            },
            {
                "name": "carbon",
                "id": 1,
                "_id": "59520442c65c73249e67fc65"
            },
            {
                "name": "iron",
                "id": 2,
                "_id": "59520442c65c73249e67fc64"
            }
        ],
        "anotherarray": [
            {
                "name": "rock",
                "id": 3,
                "_id": "59520442c65c73249e67fc69"
            },
            {
                "name": "metal",
                "id": 2,
                "_id": "59520442c65c73249e67fc68"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to write a query which will look for the `name` and `another_id` in the document as well as search through the array for the presence of `name`, say `carbon` and `iron`.

I had written a query like

```
Schema.find({
    name:"Great Name",
    arraything:{$all:['carbon','iron']}
})
```

It didn't fetch me the above document. What am I doing wrong? I am really looking for a single query object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your query looks for a document with a name of value "Great Name" and an arraything property with values "carbon" and "iron" in an array. Which is not quite what you want - you want to find where "carbon" and "iron" are values of "name" within subdocuments in that array. This should help:

```
Schema.find({
    name:"Great Name",
    arraything: { $and: [
        {$elemMatch: {name: 'carbon'}}, 
        {$elemMatch: {name: 'iron'}}
    ]}
})
```